# Jenkins Checks API could not update commit status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Multibranch pipeline with a webhook that triggers when there is a pull request to the main branch.

The pipeline has configured the option: Merging the pull request with the target branch revision.

I also set the credentials with the user that created the project and get this error:
"Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository and repo:status scope is selected"

I am not sure what the repo:status scope means.

Comment: *I am not sure what the repo:status scope means.* - In case of GitHub: https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps (and it's a checkbox to tick at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new)